# How do you evaluate this limit? $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x^5+x^2}{\sqrt{2x^{10}+x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x^5+x^2}{\sqrt{2x^{10}+x^2}}$$
This is what I have tried so far, $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x^5+x^2}{(2x^{10}+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

$$\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x^5+x^2}{(2x^{10})^{\frac{1}{2}}+(x)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\\
&\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x^5+x^2}{(2x^{5})+(x)}\\
&\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^2}{x}\\
&\lim_{x\to-\infty}x = -\infty\\
\end{align}$$
Is this the correct approach to finding the limit?

Comment: $(2x^{10}+x^2)^{\frac12}$ is not $(2x^{10})^{\frac12}+x^{\frac12}$

Comment: I would recommend multiplying top & bottom by $x^{-5}$.

Comment: This is way way too far from being correct.

Comment: I have multiplied the top and bottom by $x^{-5}$ but I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: What happens to $\frac1x$ as $x$ approaches infinity?

Comment: @gekkostate There is a square root on the bottom

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}$ would approach $0$ as $x$ approaches infinity. I think that the square root in the denominator is confusing me. I might need a better explanation on that.

Comment: What do you obtain when you divide top and bottom by $x^{-5}$?

Comment: @amWhy If the square root halves the degrees in the denominator, wouldn't the approach I took at first be correct?

Comment: @StevenN Yes, the sqrt does "slash" degrees but your approach to it is incorrect. For example, $\sqrt{x^2} \neq x$ instead it equals $|x|$. Refer to this question for an explanation http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308103/silly-question-why-is-sqrt9x2-not-3x. So for your denominator it would actually be $\sqrt{2}x^5 + |x|$

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505085/when-computing-lim-x-to-infty-frac2x7-sqrtx22x-1-i-dont-get-2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that for $x<0$, we have $$\begin{align}\sqrt{2x^{10}+x^2} &= \left(\sqrt{x^2}\right)^5\sqrt{2+\frac1{x^8}}\\ &= |x|^5\sqrt{2+\frac1{x^8}}\\ &= -x^5\sqrt{2+\frac1{x^8}}.\end{align}$$ Does that get you started?

---

Let me approach this two other ways, rigorously, and loosely. Note that the function is **undefined** for $x=0$, so we will only consider $x\neq 0$ in the following. To study the end behavior of this function, we will ultimately be interested only in the terms of highest degree on top and on bottom. Ideally, we'd like to rewrite the quotient in an equivalent way so that at least one of the highest degree terms is *constant*. Once we've done that, we'll proceed to the limit. I will call the function $f(x).$

***Rigorous***:

You expressed a desire to divide top and bottom by $x^5,$ so I will do it that way. The key fact that I will be using several times is that for any real $\alpha,$ we have $$|\alpha|=\sqrt{\alpha^2}.$$ The following manipulations hold for **any** $x\neq 0:$ $$\begin{align}f(x) &= \frac{2x^5+x^2}{\sqrt{2x^{10}+x^2}}\\ &= \frac{x^{-5}}{x^{-5}}\cdot\frac{2x^5+x^2}{\sqrt{2x^{10}+x^2}}\\ &= \frac{x^{-5}(2x^5+x^2)}{x^{-5}\sqrt{2x^{10}+x^2}}\\ &= \frac{2+x^{-3}}{x^{-5}\sqrt{x^2(2x^8+1)}}\\ &= \frac{2+x^{-3}}{x^{-5}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{2x^8+1}}\\ &= \frac{2+x^{-3}}{x^{-5}|x|\sqrt{2x^8+1}}\\ &= \frac{x}{|x|}\cdot\frac{2+x^{-3}}{x^{-4}\sqrt{2x^8+1}}.\end{align}$$ Observe that $x^{-4}$ is **positive** for all $x\neq 0,$ so in particular, $$x^{-4}=\left|x^{-4}\right|=\sqrt{(x^{-4})^2}=\sqrt{x^{-8}}.$$

Hence, we have $$\begin{align}f(x) &= \frac{x}{|x|}\cdot\frac{2+x^{-3}}{x^{-4}\sqrt{2x^8+1}}\\ &= \frac{x}{|x|}\cdot\frac{2+x^{-3}}{\sqrt{x^{-8}}\sqrt{2x^8+1}}\\ &= \frac{x}{|x|}\cdot\frac{2+x^{-3}}{\sqrt{x^{-8}\left(2x^8+1\right)}}\\ &= \frac{x}{|x|}\cdot\frac{2+x^{-3}}{\sqrt{2+x^{-8}}}\end{align}$$ for all $x\neq 0$. Now, note that $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2+x^{-3}}{\sqrt{2+x^{-8}}}=\sqrt{2},$$ as I believe you've already calculated. Also note that $$\frac{x}{|x|}=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }x>0,\\-1 & \text{if }x<0,\end{cases}$$ and so $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x}{|x|}=-1.$$ Therefore, $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\left[\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x}{|x|}\right]\cdot\left[\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2+x^{-3}}{\sqrt{2+x^{-8}}}\right]=-1\cdot\sqrt{2}=-\sqrt{2}.$$

***Loose***:

This gets back to what Babak S. mentions in the comment below. When dealing with end-behavior of polynomials, only the highest-degree term ultimately matters. To that end, we can (roughly speaking) "drop" all the terms in numerator and denominator *except* those of highest degree, and then find the limit that way. That is, $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) &= \lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x^5}{\sqrt{2x^{10}}}\\ &= \lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x^5}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^{10}}}\\ &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^5}{\sqrt{(x^5)^2}}\\ &= \sqrt{2}\cdot\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^5}{|x^5|}\\ &= \sqrt{2}\cdot\lim_{x\to-\infty}-1\\ &= -\sqrt{2}.\end{align}$$

Comment: I am trying to follow along. In the end, the absolute value becomes negative because x is approaching negative infinity or that $x<0$?

Comment: Both, actually. As $x$ approaches $-\infty$, we will eventually have $x<0$, at which point we will have $|x|=-x$.

Comment: @StevenN: Note that if you have $a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$ and $x$ goes to $\infty$ then $$a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0\sim a_nx^n$$ So $\sqrt{2x^{10}+x^2}\sim\sqrt{2}|x^5|=\sqrt{2}\times(-x^5)$ since $x\to-\infty$

Comment: Nice, Cameron! +1

Comment: So would the limit be $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: @StevenN: Close. You accidentally changed signs somewhere. It should be $$\frac{2}{-\sqrt 2}=-\frac{2}{\sqrt 2}=-\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: @CameronBuie I changed the signs because it was $-x^5$, as x approaches negative infinity, wouldn't it become positive since the two negatives cancel out?

Comment: @StevenN: Ah! I see what happened. The next step would be to rewrite $$\cfrac{2x^5+x^2}{-x^5\sqrt{2+\frac1{x^8}}}=\cfrac{2+\frac1{x^3}}{-\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{x^8}}},$$ so while it's true that $-x^5$ is positive, $x^5$ is negative, and so their quotient leaves the $-$ sign in there.

Comment: @CameronBuie *edit: Nvm I understand what you are trying to say now :).

Comment: @CameronBuie I am going over this problem again and got confused as to why the final answer is a negative when there aren't any negatives in the original function. The first step my professor took was dividing both the numerator and denominator by $-x^5$. What made him divide by a negative instead of a positive?

Comment: @StevenN: The big thing to remember is that for any positive even integer $n,$ we have $$\sqrt[n]{\alpha^n}=|\alpha|,\tag{#}$$ and for $\alpha<0$ we have $$|\alpha|=-\alpha.\tag{##}$$ He probably divided by $-x^5$ to get $-x^{-5}$ in the denominator. For $x<0,$ we can rewrite this as $|x^{-5}|$ by $(\#\#),$ and then rewrite again as $$\sqrt{\left(x^{-5}\right)^2}=\sqrt{x^{-10}}$$ by $(\#).$ Then we have $$\sqrt{x^{-10}}\sqrt{2x^{10}+x^2}=\sqrt{x^{-10}\left(2x^{10}+x^2\right)}=\sqrt{2+x^{-8}}$$ in the denominator, while his first step left $-(2+x^{-3})$ in the numerator. Same result.

Comment: @CameronBuie I am still confused as to why he divided by a negative instead of a positive. I did the same steps but divided by a positive and the answer came out as a positive $\sqrt{2}$. I think I am missing a concept here...

Comment: @StevenN: I have expanded my answer to hopefully give you a few more ways to see it. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: @CameronBuie I just watched a video by PatrickJMT and he explained it very clearly. Thank you for your answer though :D.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you can't get rid of a square root, put everything in a square root. Notice that for $x$ sufficiently negative--in particular, for $x<-\frac1{\sqrt[3]2}$--we have $2x^5+x^2<0,$ so that $$2x^5+x^2=-|2x^5+x^2|=-\sqrt{(2x^5+x^2)^2}$$ for sufficiently negative $x$-values. Thus, for such $x$-values, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2x^5+x^2}{\sqrt{2x^{10}+x^2}}
&= \frac{-\sqrt{(2x^5+x^2)^2}}{\sqrt{2x^{10}+x^2}} \\
&= -\sqrt{\frac{(2x^5+x^2)^2}{2x^{10}+x^2}} \\
&= -\sqrt{\frac{4x^{10}+4x^7+x^4}{2x^{10}+x^2}} \\
&= -\sqrt{2+\frac{4x^{10}+4x^7+x^4-2(2x^{10}+x^2)}{2x^{10}+x^2}} \\
&= -\sqrt{2+\frac{4x^7+x^4-2x^2}{2x^{10}+x^2}} \\
&= -\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{4x^7+x^4-2x^2}{4x^{10}+2x^2}} \\
\end{align}
$$

The fraction inside the right-hand square root is about
$1/x^3$,
so the right-hand square root goes to $1$ as $x\to-\infty$,
so the whole thing goes to
$-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: That doesn't work when the numerator is negative, Marty, but you're close.

Comment: Good point. But my formatting is pretty good:)

Comment: Indeed. All you really need to do to fix it is to say that for $x$ sufficiently negative, we have $$2x^5+x^2=-\sqrt{\left(2x^5+x^2\right)^2},$$ and so all the rest is basically right, just missing a $-$ sign.