# When computing $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{2x+7}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}}$, I don't get -2.

Tags: limits

This limit:

> $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{2x+7}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}}$

is supposed to be equal to **-2**. My textbook and Wolfram Alpha both state that. However, I can't seem to get same exact result.

Here's what I tried to do:

> $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{2x+7}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}} = \lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x+7}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}} \cdot \frac{1 \over x}{1 \over x} = \lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\frac{x}{x}\cdot(2+\frac7x)}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}\cdot(1+\frac{2}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2})}} = \frac{1\cdot(2+0)}{\sqrt{1\cdot(1+0-0)}} =\frac{2}{\sqrt{1}}=2$$

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Try L'Hopital's rule of infinity-over-infinity

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/315471/28900).

Comment: @user83845 I know about L'Hopital's rule, but I do this to prepare for exam and they tend to forbid the use of L'Hopital.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake at the second $=$ where you use $\frac{1}{x}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ which is false when $x$ is negative. The correct formula is $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ which gives $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ in your case.

Comment: Oh, I think I know where problem is now. So if $x\to - \infty$, we can say that $-\frac{1}{x} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}$, right?

Comment: @Saraph : Yes :)

Comment: Alright, thank you. Your answer made me realize where my brain fails to operate correctly. I'm a bit smarter now. ;)

Comment: @Saraph : It's not your brain. It is a very very very common mistake. I believe everyone has done it at least once. The important thing is to avoid it in the future :)

Answer (score 3):

We have that : $\frac{2x+7}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}}=\frac{x(2+\frac{7}{x})}{\sqrt{x^2(1+\frac{2}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2})}}=\frac{x(2+\frac{7}{x})}{(\left | x \right |)\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}}}$. Now use the fact that $\left | x \right |=-x$ for negative $x$ and youre done.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Think about the signs of the numerator and denominator in the last step. If $x\to -\infty$, then what happens to $2x + 7$? If you take the positive square root on the denominator, then what is the sign of the quotient?