# How to find the value of $ \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{4x}{\sqrt{16x^2 + 1}}$

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{4x}{\sqrt{16x^2 + 1}}$$
The result should be -1 but how

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Note that $u^2+1=u^2(1+u^{-2})$.

Comment: Welcome to the site! There are many similar problems to yours.  For example check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317308/how-do-you-evaluate-the-following-limit?noredirect=1). There are different ways to search, you can use search bar on here or you can use [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%20%5Cto%20-%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B4x%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B16x%5E2%20%2B%201%7D%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not engaging.

Answer (score 1):

converting the limit from tending to +$\infty$ instead of -$\infty$ makes it easier to work with, so that you don't commit errors and get 1 as the answer.

convert to:

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{-4x}{\sqrt{16x^2+1}}$

now it's easy. just divide both the numerator and denominator by 4x
so we divide under the square root and get

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1 +{\frac{1}{16x^2}}}}$

= -1